# UICollectionView with different layouts in each section

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a `UICollectionView` where I want to have a specific height of the cells in the `section 0` and `section 1`. In `section 2` I want two cells to look like this:

Cell 1 - Cell 2

Cell 3 - Cell 4

Cell 5 - Cell 6

The height of the CollectionViewCells in section 2 should be based on the content, but the width should be the same. I want the cells to be top aligned, so it won't look like the WaterFallLayout

Comment: What's your question? So far you've only stated requirements. Update your question (don't reply in a comment) with the relevant code you've tried so far and clearly explain what you need help with.

Comment: Please see UICollectionView FlowLayout Delegate